Recharts Barchart: How to limit bar width and spacing between bar
Instead of the default evenly distributed bars, I'm trying to achieve this result:

I want this because in larger screens the bars are too far from each other, I need to keep this max distance between then.
but I'm failing, when I set the barSize the barCategoryGap automatically becomes 'auto'. it seems like they cancel each other.


<BarChart
      (other props...)
      barCategoryGap={80}
    > 
    ...
  <Bar barSize={80} (other props...) />
</BarChart>



I'm missing something here?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stacked-bar-chart-forked-ccn3kr

I don't think any of these settings actually change the position of where the ticks (or center of the bars) are rendered. They are all for changing the bar size at the end of the day

Thank you. I ended up doing a trick to achieve the result: set the maxBarSize to 80, and get the container width using onResize in ResponsiveContainer.
From that I do the math: ( totalWidth - ((maxBarSize + barSpacing) * barCount) ) / 2
So basically I get the width of the bars plus spacing, subtract it from totalWidth, then divide by 2 to apply the padding in each side.
Due to variance values on recharts dimensions, sometime the gap is not exacly 80px but I can live with that.
